# How to login only via access token

Tags: php, authentication

Is there a way to use only access token to login via api?

```
$mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login("...", "...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an access token to authenticate API calls, but the client library you're using must support passing the access token in the HTTP Authentication header.  Here's an example from the Python simple-salesforce library:
https://github.com/heroku/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py#L114

That works for the REST based API's.  For the Metadata API (or I think other SOAP API's), the access token is set in the SOAP envelope.  Here's an example:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/mrbelvedere/blob/master/mpinstaller/mdapi.py#L34